# Call another function or variable inside a companion object android kotlin from main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-companion

Please help call another function outside the companion in Kotlin android main activity

```kotlin
class MainActivity{
    val name = "stackoverflow"

    companion object(){
        //call the both the name and showDialog from this main thread
    }
    
    fun showDialog(){
        Dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to showDialog in MainActivity. let's say other fragments or maybe from MainActivity itself.

Best approaches from this :

1. Share viewModel and have livData that lets the observer in MainActivity know to launch Dialog.
2. Call (requireActivity as? MainActivity).showDialog() from fragment hosted in MainActivity.

Comment: Please note: MainActivity does not have the viewModel since the design is based on single activity architecture.

Comment: u don't need to have a dedicated viewModel for Mainactivity but what's stopping you to share ViewModel between your fragment and activity.